# Wondering why response data map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

When I am doing a console log on response.data, it display the data on the console, but when I did a response.data.map, it show an error response.data.map is not a function. I am wondering what is wrong? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
   const GetPost = async(id) =>{
    const response = await Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/getPost',
                                   {postId:id}, {withCredentials:true})
    const getData = response.data.map(item => {
        if(item._id==response._id){
            return response
        }
        else{
            return item
        }
       
    })
   setData(getData)
}
```

Comment: Is `response.data` an array?

Comment: you get this error message when you do a .map on something that's not array, make sure response.data is not an object for example

Comment: Could you please the response which you recieved?

Comment: as mentioned by @Versifiction. your `fetch` data might not be an `array`. Please show your `fetch data`

Comment: sorry, it not an array. Thanks for helping me to see where I have gone wrong.